# Poincare lemma for rectangles and compactly supported forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am a bit stuck in understanding the proof of the Poincare lemma and a bit hung up on a certain part (I am following the book by Guillemin and Haine for what it is worth).  The result that they are trying to prove is that on a connected open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\omega \in \Omega^n_c(U)$ with $\int_U \omega = 0$, then $\omega = d \eta$ for some $\eta \in \Omega^{n-1}_c(U)$.  The proof is roughly in two steps: (1) prove the result for $U$ a rectangle, and (2) use the rectangle case to prove the more general case.  I am stuck on step (1).

For concreteness, I am trying to just understand the proof for $n = 2$ and to fix notation, the rectangle $R = [0,1] \times [0,1]$.  Let $\omega$ be compactly supported form on $R$, and further assume that $\int_R \omega = 0$.  I would like to understand how I construct a compactly-supported 1-form $\eta$ on $R$ with $d \eta = \omega$.  Can someone show me how to prove this?

(For what it is worth, the relevant part of the book is Theorem 3.2.3 - I don't understand the mechanics or the motivation for the proof.)

Comment: Have you done the proof in the case $n=1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I understand that in dimension one, given $f \, dx \in \Omega^1_c([0,1])$ with $\int f = 0$ I can just take $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$.  I'd like to see how to upgrade that to dimension 2.

Comment: Given $\omega = h(x,y)dx\wedge dy$, define $\theta=\big(\int_0^1 h(x,y)dy\big)dx$. Then $\theta$ is back in the $1$-dim situation. Now what?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, we then have $\int \theta = \int \omega = 0$ so we can antidifferentiate $\theta$ while remaining compactly-supported. But I'm not sure how to use that the antidifferentiate $\omega$ in a compactly-supported way.